# Pandas parsing dates with timezone offset not returning dtype of datetime, just object?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, timezone-offset

I have a dates column with timezone offset of +01:00 and +00:00 so the time offset is different but the same format should stay.
E.G

```
2019-05-21T00:00:00+01:00
2018-12-10T00:00:00+00:00
```

I have tried to parse this by letting pandas automatically define the time by using:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Effective_Date'])
```

which just changes the column from

```
2019-05-06T00:00:00+01:00
to
2019-05-06 00:00:00+01:00
```

Yet my column when I run `df.dtypes`is still of type object - which I believe is due to the different time offset differences?

Have also tried

`pd.to_datetime(df['Effective_Date'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')`

But this didn't work either

How do I let pandas convert my times and then return a type of datetime, and not type object?

Any help much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible - pandas TimeSeries need same `offset`.

If check `type`s it return for each `datetime` correct offset, so unfortunately cannot use vectorized datetimelike functions, because output is `Series` of `datetime`s:

```
print (pd.to_datetime(df['Effective_Date']))
0    2019-05-21 00:00:00+01:00
1    2018-12-10 00:00:00+00:00
Name: Effective_Date, dtype: object

print (pd.to_datetime(df['Effective_Date']).apply(type))
0    <class 'datetime.datetime'>
1    <class 'datetime.datetime'>
Name: Effective_Date, dtype: object
```

Check difference:

```
print (df)
              Effective_Date
0  2019-05-21T00:00:00+01:00
1  2018-12-10T00:00:00+01:00

print (pd.to_datetime(df['Effective_Date']))
0   2019-05-21 00:00:00+01:00
1   2018-12-10 00:00:00+01:00
Name: Effective_Date, dtype: datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(60)]

print (pd.to_datetime(df['Effective_Date']).apply(type))
0    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...
1    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...
Name: Effective_Date, dtype: object
```

Comment: Shame it is not possible to do this, but not to worry thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get pandas to recognise this as a datetime object, by using `tz_convert()` to apply the timezone to the datetimes. This is after using applying `parse_dates` to the dataframe during `read_csv`

My code:
`df['Effective_Date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).tz_convert('Europe/London'))`

Output before/after:

```
0    2019-05-06 00:00:00+01:00
1    2018-03-28 00:00:00+01:00
2    2018-03-28 00:00:00+01:00
3    2019-05-07 00:00:00+01:00
4    2019-02-28 00:00:00+00:00
Name: Effective_Date, dtype: object
0   2019-05-06 00:00:00+01:00
1   2018-03-28 00:00:00+01:00
2   2018-03-28 00:00:00+01:00
3   2019-05-07 00:00:00+01:00
4   2019-02-28 00:00:00+00:00
Name: Effective_Date, dtype: datetime64[ns, Europe/London]
```